# total number of products rather than individual variations

Tags: php

product I have product (A) that has size and colour variations, multiples of this product are added to the cart. There are rules set that say a minimum of 'x' of 1 product can be customised.

My code currently displays the rule message, however, it considers every line (product variation) as it's own qty and not adding them together as one qty so for example.

product (A) colour Green x 1  (WARNING MESSAGE DISPLAYED)
Product (A) colour Red x 1    (WARNING MESSAGE DISPLAYED)
Product (A) colour Blue x 6    No warning message :-)

There needs to be a min qty of 6 of product (A) to qualify for customisation so what should have happened is 1 + 1 + 6 = no error message.

Here is my current code..

Comment: If I read it correctly...You have a Product and then a subset of those.  The program is counting the subsets as individuals instead of as the 'whole'.  Can you not just have a variable for the parent set and if a subset is a member of that set then increment it and run the condition on that?

Comment: @SteveGreen , thanks for your comments. I'm VERY new to PHP, in fact I'm learning via online tutorials and trying to fix a broken site. Please forgive my naivety but basically I've learnt everything I do by self teaching. I have found some code elsewhere in the site that combines variations to a single qty, can you please show me how I could combine these to make it work?

Comment: I think you better show the code